# How to check and replace if a dataframe contains any vector element in R?

Tags: r

The dataframe and vector is shown as below:

```
df1 <- c("A1","B1","C1")
df2 <- data.frame(x = seq(1,4,1),
                  y = c("A1QWERT","B1ASD","C1ZXCV","D1TYU"))
```

I want to check if df2 y-column value contains any df1 values and replace y-column. So it will be A1, B1, C1, NA.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

One way using `str_extract` can be to paste `df1` together as one pattern  and extract the value from `df2$y`

```
stringr::str_extract(df2$y, paste0(df1, collapse = "|"))
#[1] "A1" "B1" "C1" NA
```

Or a  base-R way using `sapply`

```
df2$y1 <- sapply(df2$y, function(x) {
    inds = sapply(df1, grepl, x)
    if (any(inds)) df1[which.max(inds)] else NA
})

df2
#  x       y   y1
#1 1 A1QWERT   A1
#2 2   B1ASD   B1
#3 3  C1ZXCV   C1
#4 4   D1TYU <NA>
```